# Uniden FW Hacking

Tags: assembly, firmware, file-format, cryptography

I recently purchased a Uniden Radio Scanner (BCD325P2). I looked at the Windows FW Update App in dnSpy, then pulled the FW bin directly.

FCC Parts List gets me R5F5631BCDFP#V0, which appears to be a Renesas Electronics 32-bit Microcontrollers - MCU RX631 1MB/128KB.

The latest FW bin for this model is here:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/vp2drmh7dvgjpfi/BCD325P2_V1_08_01.bin/file

The FW bin looks packed or obfuscated, there are no strings and binwalk shows nothing.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

I would really like to get this loaded into a disassembler.

Comment: Check if the fw update app does any decryption before sending it to the device.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking last night, although nothing obvious stands out I still have to go through it more carefully. This gets me thinking... is it very unusual for FW to be encrypted/obfuscated outside the device? .... thanks Igor.

Comment: not too common, but it does happen